# Install docker engine on red hat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, docker

I'm getting these errors on docker installation.

i have this linux distr:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-031.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Sep 10 13:42:16 EDT 2015
```

and the errors:

```
---> Package docker-engine.x86_64 0:1.8.3-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.8.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: docker-engine-1.8.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-engine-1.8.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (dockerrepo)
           Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: docker-engine-1.8.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (dockerrepo)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i have these library installed,but the docker installation don't find them:

```
./lib/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6
./lib/libc.so.6
./lib64/libc.so.6
```

I don't know how i can install `systemd-units`.

Could someone provide me an explanation?

thanks in advance.

Comment: tried sudo ldconfig ?